# Update SQL in Python

Tags: python, sql

Here is my code and my intention is to update SQL database in python. But when I run this code and go back to SQL. The table was not updated. I do include the connection.commit() to save the changes.

```
def id_update()

    
     connection_str = ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                  "Server=a;"
                  "Database=b;"
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

    connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_str)

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    prepare_sql="""  
   
    Select * into #id
    from B_table as b 
    inner join 
           (Select distinct isin, issuerid 
            from  A_table
            where issuerid is not null and updatedate>='2022-06-30') as a 
    on a.isin=b.security_isin and b.[as_of_date]='2022-06-30'  
    where b.id is null"""
    
    update_sql= """  
    
    update B_table
    set B_table.id=b.issuerid, 
    --Select *
    from B_table as a
    left join #id as b 
    on a.security_isin=b.security_isin """
    
    # Execute
    cursor.execute(prepare_sql)
    cursor.execute(update_sql)
    
    
    # Drop temporary table
    cursor.execute("drop table #id")
    
    # Save changes
    connection.commit()
    
    connection.close()
```

My logic is that I first get the update info in to temporary table #id and then update the existing datable by using this temporary table.

When I call function, there is no error but it was not updated if I go back to SQL database.

But if I run this chunk of code in SQL, the table can be updated successfully.

Comment: I don't think you can run that code, because it has a syntax error (a missing colon). Please show the actual code you've used.

Comment: ... or *almost* actual, if you want to use phony credentials.

Comment: Please see the updated one. Thank you

Comment: There's a comma too much, your temporary table is called #id when you create it and #ev_id when you drop it, both of which are syntax errors. And don't use string formatting to fill in values in SQL queries; use [proper methodes for passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. Please see the updated one. I get rid of the format.

Comment: There's still a stray comma, I think. Anyway, what I would do, once the syntax is sorted out, is: 1) check that the temporary table contains what I expect and, if it does, 2) run a SELECT selecting the same rows as the UPDATE is supposed to touch, and verify that *that* returns what I expect.